# div floating position on image

Tags: jquery, html, css

My problem is this the `.figure` field is 100% but `.recomddo` no position on the image without going to the corner of `.figure` , what I want is that `.recomddo` on position img

How could achieve this effect with jQuery or css, we appreciate the help

```css
        figure.envoltura {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 40px;
        }
        figure {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .page_img {
            border: 2px solid #ddd;
            background-color: #fff;
         max-width: 100%;
        }
        .recomddo, .recomddo:before {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            line-height: 40px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
        }
        .recomddo {
            position: absolute;
            background-color: #F1C40F;
            top: 10px;
            right: -10px;
            border-radius: 5px 5px 0 5px;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        .recomddo:after {
            width: 0;
            height: 0;
            border-top: 10px solid #C19D0C;
            border-right: 10px solid transparent;
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            bottom: -10px;
            right: 0;
        }
```

```html
      <figure id="fig_solo" class="envoltura">
            <img class="page_img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
         <span class="recomddo">1</span>
        </figure>
```

Comment: You've set figure.envoltura to display: block - it's filling the whole width. Does it need to be 100%?

Comment: Can the markup be changed?

Comment: my interest is that `.recomddo` this on the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.recomddo {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F1C40F;
    top: 0px;
    left: 322px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Hope This work with you.

Comment: This works for that image that I used as a placeholder that's 350px wide, but probably not holistically.